# jenkins withEnv pipeline no longer working

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a previously working Jenkins pipeline where I am inserting an environment variable into a step using `withEnv`:

```
stage('Set build number'){
      steps {
        sh 'chmod +x scripts/setBuildVersion.sh'
        withEnv(['DEPLOY_VERSION=$env.GIT_COMMIT']) {
          sh 'scripts/setBuildVersion.sh'
        }
      }
    }
```

inside the `setBuildVersion.sh` script, I have the following content:

```
        printenv
    sed -i "s/@@BUILD_NUMBER@@/Version $DEPLOY_VERSION/g" deployment.properties
```

I find that `printenv` command can see my `$DEPLOY_VERSION` environment variable.
I have tried many different ways of editing my `sed` command, but `withEnv` treats the input as text, so `$DEPLOY_VERSION` is replaced by the string `$env.GIT_COMMIT` instead of the value of the variable.

What am I missing here? This is running on a Linux Jenkins version 2.138.2 server. Thank you for any guidance you can give.

Answer (score 0):

use `${env.GIT_COMMIT}` 
instead of `$env.GIT_COMMIT`

Comment: Sadly this appears to still print it exactly as text. I am using $DEPLOY_VERSION in the shell script.

Comment: I gave up on using a separate file and did this in the jenkins file:

    DEPLOY_VERSION='valuehere'

For all of my values.